# What strategies can I use to keep a separate variable to denote money for saving, but be able to render a formatted string for display?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

What strategies can I use to keep a separate variable to denote money for saving, but be able to render a formatted string for display? How can I make an input that will display a number formatted as currency/money (using periods instead of commas, and also no cent value), but save the original value to persist?

`1000` => `1.000`

`1000000` => `1.000.000`

Example: When saved it should be inserted into the database as `1000`, and `1000000` not as `1.000` or `1.000.000`, respectively.

Comment: you could remove the dots before inserting it to db with for example: input_str.split('.').join('') - there are more elegant solutions tho...

Comment: try something like https://jsfiddle.net/1o7zkjgd/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry , i just got a solution for this.
I am found and use this plugin : https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin instead do it jscript natively.
and i write something like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#formharga').mask('000.000.000', {reverse: true});
});
$("#formpaket").submit(function() {
  $("#formharga").unmask();
});
```

and the problem solved !
Thanks guys for help.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

```
var yourNum='1,825.00'
yourNum = yourNum.replace(/\,/g,'')
var finalNum = Number(yourNum)
//this give 1825
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this, very simply put, is to use a function that will return a new string based on the input. This way you can get the formatted number but are not modifying/mutating the actual variable. Then, when you save, don't use the string returned by the function, rather, use the original un-mutated variable...

```
// Use a function that will return the value to render without mutating the original value...

function getFormattedNumber(num) {
    return num.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
}

// This way 'num' stays the same and can be saved

var n = 1000000; 

var formatted = getFormattedNumber(n) // => 1.000.000
```

Comment: This is assuming that 1) You don't want the '$' sign and 2) You want '.' instead of  ',' and also 3) That you won't ever have periods denoting cents...

Comment: Use pure functions wherever you can. A pure function does not mutate anything outside itself. A pure function does not produce side effects. Given the same inputs, a pure function will always return the same output.